# How to read the notification message to alert the user in my application?

Tags: android, notifications, file-transfer

I have implemented the file transfer using bluetooth. Once the file transfer completes it shows me the notification of

> File success 1 failed 0           in the notofication bar.

How can I read this mobile notification message. To show the user for successful sent or failed in my application.

Comment: this is help you : https://github.com/willhou/Bluetooth-Notification

Comment: I think that's for Bluetooth connect or disconnect. But for me need it for me to read the notification message for success or failure file transfer.